# Project type to implement a receiving 'server' app

Tags: c#

I'm developing a server app for the client that I've already made. The idea is that the client(s) throughout the day create files (serialized objects) that, at the end of the day, need to make their way to the server so that those files can be analyzed and have their data inserted into the main db.

I'm wondering if there is a better project type to implement this:

- Web service where the webmethod just gets called with the object that needs to be uploaded is accepted as a param.
- Windows service that just waits on a port and accepts the data.
- Ftp server with a program that just filewatches the ftp upload folder and grabs the data when it's uploaded.
- Anything I haven't thought of

I'm leaning towards the first, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably leaning to the first because it is easiest! And easiest is usually best!

Web Services are very comprehensive and can offer anything from a simple GET to a complex WCF-enabled service. Security may be added on by HTTPS and authentication with ease. Web Services/WCF may not cope well with massive files, but you could think about splitting them up into packets.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the first would be the simplest choice, much of your infrastructure (authentication and protocol managment stand out) is already in place. So you can concentrate on the logic of the application.